# Manage Multiple Microservices git repos in one jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have 25 git repos having java spring boot code. I am using Jenkinsfile to run pipeline and have put the file under root of all repos.

I am currently using "Pipeline script from SCM" in pipeline project and added 25 repos in that (check image). added git webhook as well.  But when there is git commit in  2 or 3 repos simultaneously, it only process first one. I run the job manually for other changes.

I want if we run the pipeline it should pickup all changes from all repos and run the pipeline from SCM's jenkinsfile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In that case it would be easier to just have one repository with the jenkinsfile (like a ci/cd repository). You then just use the git step for all repositories you want to build.

If you only want to build the repository that changed you might want to use webhooks and only build the repo url you received as a parameter.